# How to disable range of dates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I need to disable the range of dates given by l1 and l2. The method I've tried only disables l1 i.e. The date 13.

```
var l1 = new Date("2019-07-13");
var l2 = new Date("2019-07-30");
this.flag =0;

  this.filter2 = function(date) {
    /*if(this.minDate == b){
        flag=1;
        }
        return flag;*/
        var c = date.getDate();
        for(i=l1.getDate();i<=l2.getDate();i++)
        {
            return c!=i;
            continue;
        }
        //return c!=l1.getDate() && c!=l2.getDate();
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by disabling this range of dates? you want to create a method that ignores dates between the given l1 and l2 ?

Comment: code will not execute further `return`, what you are doing in the first iteration itself.

Comment: Ionut Ardelean Yes,I am trying to do exactly that.

Comment: @ArunSunny see my answer below and the comments

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the ms timestamp of the date is between the ms timestamps of the `l1` and `l2`

```js
var l1 = new Date("2019-07-30");
var l2 = new Date("2019-07-13");

function filter(date) {
  if (date instanceof Date && l1 instanceof Date && l2 instanceof Date) {
      return l1.getTime() < l2.getTime() ? !(date.getTime() >= l1.getTime() && date.getTime() <= l2.getTime()) : !(date.getTime() >= l2.getTime() && date.getTime() <= l1.getTime())
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}

console.log(filter(new Date("2019-07-13")));
console.log(filter(new Date("2019-07-12")));
```

Comment: switching l1 and l2 between them if the input params are not correct is not the best option. in an app, this could weird UX problems. although validations should not let you get this far.

Comment: Do you mean if some of the inputs are not a Date? If so, I've added a piece of code that checks if all of them are Dates.

Comment: no I mean, that in the real life application if a user set's the dates wrong, the solution would bot be to switch them between, to if l1 > l2 it should either have a validation problem on the UI let's say, and the method should not work either way. it can be confusing to have a method that filters out dates based on l1 and l2, no matter in what timely order l1 and l2 are given

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps work great, but also consider my comments please

```js
var l1 = new Date("2019-07-13");
var l2 = new Date("2019-07-30"); 
// l2 will result in a date like this Sun Jul 30 2019 00:00:00 so if you want for it to only work for 2019-08-01, better use directly 2018-08-01
// or set l2 to new Date("2019-07-30 23:59:59.999")

// this method will return true if the date value the function gets as a parameter is outside the given range
// for dates like: 2019-07-12 but as i specified above it will work for today's date since getTime method also consider hours, minutes, seconds and // milliseconds
this.filter2 = function(date) {
  return l1.getTime() < l2.getTime() && (date.getTime() < l1.getTime() || date.getTime() > l2.getTime())
}

console.log(filter2(new Date())) //in today's case given the mentions above it will return true
console.log(filter2(new Date('2019-07-15'))) // false
console.log(filter2(new Date('2019-07-12'))) // true
```

Comment: This code will not work if l1 is a further date than l2.

Comment: I agree I have not checked l1 and l2, but that was not the purpose of the questions. good catch anyhow, thanks !

Comment: Yes, it's not the purpose but there wasn't any indications on the post saying l2 is always going to be a further date so I think we should take extra precautions. You are welcome!

Comment: By the way, every date returns false in the snippet. I think there's a mistake since 2019-07-12 is not between the given dates.

Comment: I've missed the parentheses for l2.getTime() on the first comparison between l1 and l2. my bad